# Remove change button in Jasny fileinput widget

Tags: php, jquery, css, file-upload, jasny-bootstrap

I integrated [Jasny Fileinput](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput) Widget into my existing form. When I select new file, It will display two button: Change and Remove. I think Change button is not neccessary in this case so I would like to remove this button completely. By adding style="display:none" to the element and I also try to remove this element. However, this still appear a blank spot like this:
    [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giangvy1011/fwetvug5/).

MY HTML:

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-exists" data-provides="fileinput">
<div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" />
</div>
<div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" /></div>
<div>
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span style="display:none" class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="file[]"></span>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how to remove this completely please?

Comment: set `display none` to it's parent element?

Comment: Yes i did set it in this : <span style="display:none" class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>

Comment: The @u_mulder comment is correct. You have to set display:none to the parent, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fwetvug5/1/). Anyway, it doesn't have much sense given that the button has the input inside.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you'll be able to remove that button completely. As that button belongs to the file input, you can't remove it. You could however write custom styles to hide the file input button but it may hide other buttons that are associated with it.

Sorry I couldn't help any further mate.